Qu'est-ce que cet expert dit ?
(Je m'excuse pour l'imprécison du titre de cette question)
Dans l’épisode du 10 Septembre 2024, intitulé « Pourquoi et comment explorer la mécanique intime des fluides ? » du podcast Autour de la question de RFI le chercheur Laurent Chauvaud discute les phénomènes contre-intuitifs. Il dit (ou semble dire) au repère de temps de 11:19

la physique trimbale plein de paradigmes comme ça qui sont archiques.

Je n'ai pas compris ce dernier... euh... mot (?). Et je ne l'ai trouvé ni chez Robert ni dans Wiktionniare
ni dans le TLFi. Donc je me suis demandé, quelles sont les interprétations alternatives? Est-ce qu'il a dit archaïque ? (Non, pas de /k/. J'entends /ʃ/.) Est-ce qu'il a dit anarchique ? (Non, je n'entends pas de préfixe /an/.) S'agit-il d'un orthographe alternatif ? Harchiques ? (Non, aucune trace de ceci non plus dans les dicos.)
Ben, en fin de compte, il ne nous reste qu'une seule possibilité : ce qu'il a dit, c'est harres chics. [je plaisante.]
Quelle est la transcription effective ?

Il s'apprêtait à dire quelque chose comme qui sont archi-contre-intuitifs mais a changé d'avis en cours de route, peut-être parce qu'il s'est rendu compte qu'il se répétait, ne disant finalement qu'archic et enchaînant directement sur Einstein. D'un certain point de vue, il s'est coupé lui-même la parole.

He was about to say something like qui sont archi-contre-intuitifs, i.e. extremely counter-intuitive but changed his mind halfway, maybe because he thought he was repeating himself, only leaving "archic" and moving to Einstein. He kind of cut himself off.

I suppose that that could be the case. It doesn't sound that way to me, but perhaps that's the sort of thing about which a language learner should defer to native speakers.

Yes, the fact no French word fit and the lack of ending stress doesn't leave many alternatives. He didn't changed his mind about it as that was the idea but he possibly noticed that he was repeating himself so he moved on, talked about Einstein and left the sentence unfinished.

He said precisely: "qui sont archic [y'a pas que Einstein, hein: à expliquer des choses qui sont] contre-intuitifs". It's as you wrote: he cut himself off even before ending the word archi-contre-intuitif, to insert a digression about Einstein. He managed to end it with the interrupted word and pretended the result was grammatical. A jolly daring anacoluth, is what I say.
